# rsync --exclude-from=file cannot make the relative path function correctly- how does the exclude from option

Tags: relative-path, rsync

I am trying to build a list of files to be excluded.

The absolute path works fine!
But when I try to use the relative path. I get the following error:

```
rsync: failed to open exclude file exclude-list: No such file or directory (2)rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at exclude.c(1178) [client=3.1.2]
```

the exclude-list is the file name.
It is in the source directory at the root

My syntax is

```
rsync -av --delete --exclude-from='exclude-list'  /source /destination
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Exclude and include *rules* are resolved relative to the root of the transfer, but finding *rule files* (e.g. `--exclude-from='exclude-list'`) is done relative to the working directory of the `rsync` process (which it inherits from the process that ran it). You need to use `--exclude-from='/source/exclude-list'`

Comment: Great! explanation! I created a new directory: moved file into that directory: cd command into that directory: ran command from that directory: IT WORKS! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Great! explanation from Gordon Davisson!

1. I created a new directory
2. mkdir mydir
3. moved file into that directory:
4. cd command into that directory:
5. ran command from that directory:
6. IT WORKS!